# UITableViewController with multiple segues going to the wrong view

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview, xcode5, uistoryboardsegue

So I'm completely stumped here.  I'm using xcode 5 and I have a table view with 2 segues. I tried to set the segues originally with two different prototype cells, but that didn't work.  So I now have both segues set at the UITableViewController.  It seems like whichever segue I created last is the one it goes to.  I'm not getting any errors and when I step through the code, it fires on the correct line to execute the segue.

This seems to execute perfectly every time but it just doesn't go to the correct view.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([currentTableViewType isEqualToString:@"feedbackOnly"]){
        // hits this line correctly
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSendFeedback" sender:indexPath];
    } else {
        // hits this line correctly
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowTicketDetails" sender:indexPath];
    }
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSIndexPath *)selectedIndexPath {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowTicketDetails"])
    {
        TicketDetailsViewController *tdv = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];
        Ticket * currentTicket = [ticketsArray objectAtIndex:row];
        tdv.tPriority = currentTicket.ticketPriority;
        tdv.tId = currentTicket.ticketId;
        tdv.tStatus = currentTicket.ticketStatus;
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSendFeedback"]){
        FeedbackViewController *fvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];
        Ticket * currentTicket = [ticketsArray objectAtIndex:row];
        fvc.tPriority = currentTicket.ticketPriority;
        fvc.tId = currentTicket.ticketId;
        fvc.tStatus = currentTicket.ticketStatus;
    }
}
```

To be thorough, I've included my entire controller that has the issue.

```
#import "TicketsViewController.h"
@interface TicketsViewController ()
@end
@implementation TicketsViewController
@synthesize json, ticketsArray, ticketsTableView, currentTableViewType;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Tickets";

    AppDataClass *appData=[AppDataClass getInstance];
    currentTableViewType = appData.tableViewType;
    [self retrieveData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return ticketsArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if([currentTableViewType isEqualToString:@"feedbackOnly"]){
        return @"Requires Feedback";
    } else {
        return @"Issues";
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Ticket * currentTicket = [ticketsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = currentTicket.ticketName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentTicket.ticketAddress;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    if([currentTicket.ticketPriority.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"high"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert.png"];
        if([indexPath row] % 2) [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Methods
- (void)retrieveData
{
   // NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
   // NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    AppDataClass *appData=[AppDataClass getInstance];
    NSString *args = @"userid=%@&authid=%@";
    NSString *values=[NSString stringWithFormat:args, appData.userId, appData.authId];
    json = [appData getPostData:appData.URL_LIST_TICKETS:values];

    ticketsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // segeue names
    // allTickets
    // feedbackOnly

    for(int i=0; i<json.count; i++){
        NSString * tId = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * tName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * tPriority = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"priority"];
        Ticket * myTicket = [[Ticket alloc] initWithTicketId:tId andTicketName:tName andTicketPriority:tPriority];
        [ticketsArray addObject:myTicket];
    }

    [self.ticketsTableView reloadData];

}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([currentTableViewType isEqualToString:@"feedbackOnly"]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSendFeedback" sender:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowTicketDetails" sender:indexPath];
    }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSIndexPath *)selectedIndexPath {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowTicketDetails"])
    {
        TicketDetailsViewController *tdv = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];
        Ticket * currentTicket = [ticketsArray objectAtIndex:row];
        tdv.tPriority = currentTicket.ticketPriority;
        tdv.tId = currentTicket.ticketId;
        tdv.tStatus = currentTicket.ticketStatus;
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSendFeedback"]){
        FeedbackViewController *fvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];
        Ticket * currentTicket = [ticketsArray objectAtIndex:row];
        fvc.tPriority = currentTicket.ticketPriority;
        fvc.tId = currentTicket.ticketId;
        fvc.tStatus = currentTicket.ticketStatus;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so it seems to be a bug in XCode.  I had originally copied the 2nd ViewController that I was trying to segue to and changed the class of it as well as some of the view components. I figured StoryBoard would be smart enough to reassign this view as its own.  I was wrong. XCode didn't seem to like that.  Starting from scratch with a new ViewController seems to fix everything and the segues are working correctly now.  The exact same code works.

So if anyone is having this issue, make sure you didn't copy and paste a ViewController that you are trying to segue to.  This will save you hours of headaches :-)

It probably had a reference to the same ViewController which is why whatever the last segue I setup was the only one working.

Comment: When you copied the view controller it would have copied the view controller's custom class if you had set it. If so, that's what you would have needed to update on the new view controller. See step #2 in the following link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardScene.html